# How to get GNU make 4.3 on MacOS (OS X) to be default

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

when running make at the cli it defaults to 3.81.

I have installed make 4.3 using homebrew but can't work out how to update MacOS to default to 4.3 over 3.81.

I've trawled SO and google but can't seem to find an answer.

I know I'm going to kick myself but any help appreciated.

Comment: Set the $PATH variable to find the location of 4.3 first?  Default (3.81) should be in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 1):

Duh - just seen the brew had:

```
GNU "make" has been installed as "gmake".
If you need to use it as "make", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```